# Error when passing arguments to function handles

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations, function-handle, ode45

Suppose we have the following function:

```
function f=lorenz(t,x,a,b,c)
    % solve differential equation like this
    %dx/dt=a*(y-x)
    %dy/dt=-x*z+b*x-y
    %dz/dt=xy-c*z/3
    f=zeros(3,1);% preallocate result
    f(1)=a*(x(2)-x(1));
    f(2)=-x(1)*x(3)+b*x(1)-x(2);
    f(3)=x(1)*x(2)-c*x(3)/3;
    end
```

For running this program, let us use the following test file:

```
% test program
x0=[-2 -3.5 21];% initial  point
a=input(' enter first coefficient : ');
b=input(' enter second coefficient: ');
c=input(' enter third coefficient : ');
[t,x]=ode45(@(x) lorenz(x,a,b,c),[0 10],x0);
plot(t,x(:,1),'r'); 
title(' solution of x part');
grid on
```

I have tried passing arguments to the function handle,

```
test_program
 enter first coefficient : 10
 enter second coefficient: 28
 enter third coefficient : -8
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
Error using @(x)lorenz(x,a,b,c)
Too many input arguments.

Error in odearguments (line 87)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 113)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in test_program (line 6)
[t,x]=ode45(@(x) lorenz(x,a,b,c),[0 10],x0);
```

one solution involves using global variables, like this:

```
function f=lorenz(t,x)
    % solve differential equation like this
    %dx/dt=a*(y-x)
    %dy/dt=-x*z+b*x-y
    %dz/dt=xy-c*z/3
    global a
    global b
    global c
    f=zeros(3,1);% preallocate result
    f(1)=a*(x(2)-x(1));
    f(2)=-x(1)*x(3)+b*x(1)-x(2);
    f(3)=x(1)*x(2)-c*x(3)/3;
    end
```

but then it takes too long to run.

How else can I fix this issue? What I want is to pass different arguments,  if I write inside code something like this

```
a=input('enter the coefficient : ')
```

then this will be repeated several times.

Comment: what's the `t` for in `lorenz(t,x,a,b,c)`? if it's optional, move it to the end of the input argument list (`lorenz(x,a,b,c,t)`).

Comment: t is output, or time  after ode45 is callled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use global variables.

The fix is very simple, add the `t` as input too:

```
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) lorenz(t,x,a,b,c),[0 10],x0);
```

Comment: wait   i may missed this part

Comment: but there is one problem it takes too much time

Comment: thanks for help, just one comment : when i run it, it was running without compiling final result, if i let it finish, it may take 1 hour

Comment: Strange, it takes 2 seconds to run on my regular computer

Comment: thanks in advance, i may troubleshoot tommorow, thanks in advance